# Web Service UpdateListItems User Permissions

Tags: list, permissions, web-services, javascript

I'm trying to do an AJAX SOAP call to the Lists web service, specifically UpdateListItems.  The query isn't malformed, and is working appropriately when using a user with full permissions.  When a user with contribute permission tries the query below (and the list being written to is properly permission), I get a 403 error.  Are UpdateListItems permissions set elsewhere, such as the web.config file?

**UPDATE 1**

I am using jQuery to make the AJAX call.  Following is the code used:

```
       var query = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
        <soap:Body>\
            <UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">\
            <listName>{2C3F42BF-A33D-478A-A06E-2342FFC9F3F8}</listName>\
                <updates>\
                    <Batch OnError="Continue">\
                        <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">\
                            <Field Name="Title">email@email.com</Field>\
                            <Field Name="Name">My Name</Field>\
                            <Field Name="Date"></Field>\
                        </Method>\
                     </Batch>\
                </updates>\
                </UpdateListItems>\
            </soap:Body>\
        </soap:Envelope>';
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"); },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: query,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

403 signifies that request was a legal, but the server is refusing to respond to it. Have you try setting `ListVersion` and `ViewName` attribute of `Batch` element, before sending the request?

For e.g.

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" 
ViewName="270C0508-A54F-4387-8AD0-49686D685EB2">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
      <Field Name='ID'>New</Field>
      <Field Name="Title">Value</Field>
      <Field Name="Date_Column">2007-3-25</Field>
      <Field Name="Date_Time_Column">
         2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

You can also dig into [UpdateListItemsResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd932216%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to further refine the error code.

Comment: I just tried updating the batch with both the ListVersion and ViewName, but it still returns the same 403 error.  The response XML is ==== XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{7163da59-14d5-4cad-a155-a51cafa23e98} Line Number 1, Column 1: 403 FORBIDDEN. =====  If the user has full control, they're able to use this webservice without error.  There must be settings that require a high permission level to initiate the call?

Comment: Are you using jQuery to place AJAX SOAP call? Could you please paste the whole code?

Comment: I am using jQuery.  I've updated my question to include the code for the AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found the solution.  The user's permission level was missing the site permission **Use Remote Interfaces**.  SharePoint defines it as

> Use SOAP, Web DAV, or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.

It makes perfect sense now that I look at it.  I admittedly don't know enough about SharePoint permissions, and didn't know it was that fine-grained.   I just assumed that if a user had write permissions for a list, they could write to it using any protocol.